# SQLite3 Python variables

Tags: python, sqlite

I've written this code for an SQLite3 database in python:

```
 i = datetime.datetime.now()
        v_day = i.day
        v_month = i.month
        v_year = i.year
        v_hour = i.hour
        v_minute = i.minute

    cur.execute("""INSERT INTO weather(
                day,month,year,hour,minut,temperature,humidity) VALUES (
                ?,?,?,?,?,?,?),
                (v_day,v_month,v_year,v_hour,v_minute,temp,hum)""")
```

After trying it, it displayed this Error:
  File "store_data.py", line 68, in main
    (v_day,v_month,v_year,v_hour,v_minute,temp,hum)""")
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: v_day
I've already tried to put the variables names in the VALUES' list, but I occured in the same Error.

Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
sql = f"""INSERT INTO weather(day,month,year,hour,minut,temperature,humidity) VALUES ({v_day},{v_month},{v_year},{v_hour},{v_minute},{temp},{hum})"""
cur.execute(sql)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your tuple is inside your string. Also you shouldn't denote the table columns in the query. Try

```
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO weather VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
                (v_day,v_month,v_year,v_hour,v_minute,temp,hum))
```